# Unplugin-vue-define-options TypeError

Tags: vuejs3, vite

I want to mock a http request in Vue.js using Vitest. How can I perform testing for http requests

I use unplugin-vue-define-options LTS in my Vue.js 3 + Vite 3. After running my app, the following error is appeared.

> [vite] Internal server error: unplugin-vue-define-options TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'scriptSetupAst')

I also reinstall the package, but there is still the above error.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem. But today I updated to the latest version released ([1.1.3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unplugin-vue-define-options/v/1.1.3)) and apparently this bug has been fixed.

Comment: Yes, Updating to new version solve the problem.